# Integer programming formulation of the partition problem

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming, operations-research

I have the following problem:

> Consider the set of integers $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and $$\sum_{i=1}^6 s_i i,$$ where $s_1, s_2, \dots, s_6 \in \{1,-1\}$ are the signs that appear in front of each of these numbers. Present an integer programming model that minimizes $$\left| \,\sum_{i=1}^6 s_i i \,\right|$$

I created binary variables $b_1, b_2, \dots, b_6 \in \{0,1\}$ for this linear modeling.

$$\min U$$
subject t
$$U \geq \sum_{i=1}^6 s_i i$$
$$U \geq -\sum_{i=1}^6 s_i i$$

$$s_i + 1 \leq M_1(1-b_i)$$
$$s_i - 1 \leq - M_1 + b_i$$

$$s_i = \{-1,+1\}$$
$$b_i = \{0,1\}$$
$M_1$ is big constant

My model is incorrect and I do not know how to solve

Comment: What do you mean by "the following mathematical expression: S1 1 s2 2 s3 3 s4 4 s5 5 s6 6" ?? And please see this link to reformat your post into proper math rendering: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 6):

You don't need big-M constraints for this purpose. $s_i=2b_i-1$ should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint $s_i -1 \leq -M_1 + b_i$ must be removed.

Regardless of the values of $b_i$, it is making the problem infeasible as the upper bound is a very small number.

The constraint

$$s_i + 1 \leq M_1 (1-b_1)$$
means if 
$b_i = 1$,then we must have $s_i= -1$. If $b_i=0$, $s_i$ is free.

Hence you  still need to include a constraint that says

if $b_1=0$, then we must have $s_i=1$.

$$-s_i\leq Mb_i$$

Remark:

In terms of the optimal value of the problem, since there are $3$ odd numbers, the optimal value will be at least $1$.

$$-1-2-3-4+5+6=1$$

Comment: I don't think the constraint $-s_i \le Mb_i$ is what you had in mind. for $b_i=0$, it just requires $s_i\ge 0$, which is insufficient unless the domain $s\in\{-1,1\}$ is enforced somewhere else in the model.

Comment: @prubin of course, she has to keep those constraint. thanks for bringing this up. the intention is to help her replace a wrong constraint. I think too complicated that I just look at big M method.